# Hide element only on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a question...

[I have a website developed especially for Chrome](http://rcotrina.info/), and i want to show a notification (for say people use Google Chrome) only to user they're not using Chrome. I think it should be like this on Javascript:

```
var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome/") > -1;

if (isChrome) {
document.getElementById('notification').style.display = 'none';
}
```

but when I did this, I got an error ( in Google Developer Inspector: JS Console) saying this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

so what am I doing wrong¿?

Thanks in advance.

PD. Sorry for my English, I speak a little of it!

Comment: Are you checking this after the document loads? if you check before it will be null since it's not part of the dom yet.

Comment: How do i check that? My Website is [http://rcotrina.info/](http://rcotrina.info/)

Comment: `if (isChrome = true)` is equivalent to: `isChrome = true; if(isChrome)`.

Comment: corrected, but i still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably trying to run that code before your whole HTML is read into a DOM. Register it as an event handler for the "load" or "ready" events. (The best way to do this depends on whether you're using a Javascript framework or just pure JS.)

Comment: Well, the easiest way is to do that in a way that's compatible with pretty much any browser is `window.onload = function() { your code here }`, but the downside is you can only use one such event handler on your whole site, and the event will only fire once *everything* on the page has finished loading. Fixing both in a compatible way is an annoying chunk of feature-detection code that I can't write from memory because it's usually just better to use a library like jQuery which already has a working implementation of this.

Comment: Thanks! I understood a little, but I'd appreciate if you explain me that in simple terms, because I only know a little of English.

Comment: it solved, but the item dissapear a little time after the element is loaded... what i can do?

Comment: At this point my recommendation would be using a JS library with a portable implementation of registering the "ready" event and registering the handler with it. There seems to be one that provides this functionality alone: https://github.com/ryanmorr/ondomready

Comment: thanks a lot! i solved it integrating the code above, with the js that display the notification! Thanks again. Regarts from Peru!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the element `notification` doesn't exists.

Comment: Right. And maybe it's related to @JeremySpouken comment, the script is probably being executed at loading time and the element he's looking for is not yet present. document.ready() should do

Answer (score 0):

Saying that `document.getElementById('notification')` is null so you are calling it before the element is rendered on the page.

Need to add after the element, document ready, or window onload.

Eric

Comment: Uhmm how do I do that? Can you give me an example?, please